Invisible Object
I'm trying to create a render of some cross hole drilling, my drill appears in my viewport and I have it set to be visible in the render yet it refuses to show up. I've tried to ctrl+alt+h when I have the object selected, but that doesn't work. Additionally these cross holes have booleans attached to the cube with invisible cylinders which could possibly have something to do with it. Let me know what you think.



If the drill is selected, the outliner options are ok (visible in viewport and in render). The modifiers also seem ok (no modifiers in the list). But if the drill is not selected in the print screen, maybe update the print screen. --- The next place I'd search is the "object" tab in the properties panel (right side of the screen), there are visibility options there too (not sure if render visibility options there) -Then I'd take a look in the animation, can you watch the animation in viewport? (Render will reset the position to what is in the animation, not what is in the viewport)

Daniel, Thanks for the quick reply, I'm ashamed to admit I had a keyframe leftover from a previous animation... thanks for the help though, problem resolved.
